# non-virtual template based class - leak memory?

Tags: c++

Based on the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321133544), pp338

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ostream>
#include <algorithm>

#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/cast.hpp>

using namespace std;

template <typename R, typename Arg> class invoker_base {
public:
  virtual R operator()(Arg arg)=0;
};

template <typename R, typename Arg> class function_ptr_invoker 
  : public invoker_base<R,Arg> {
  R (*func_)(Arg);
public:
  function_ptr_invoker(R (*func)(Arg)):func_(func) {}

  R operator()(Arg arg) {
    return (func_)(arg);
  }
};

template <typename R, typename Arg> class function1 {
  invoker_base<R,Arg>* invoker_;
public:
  function1(R (*func)(Arg)) : 
    invoker_(new function_ptr_invoker<R,Arg>(func)) {}

  R operator()(Arg arg) {
    return (*invoker_)(arg);
  }

  ~function1() {
    delete invoker_;
  }
};

bool some_function(const std::string& s) {
  std::cout << s << " This is really neat\n";
  return true;
}

int main() {
  function1<bool,const std::string&> f1(&some_function);
  f1(std::string("Hello"));
}
```

**Question**> the default destructor of `invoker_base` is NOT virtual. Does there exist memory leak in the implementation of `function1`? As the code indicates, the `function1::~function1` deletes the allocated resource through a non-virtual base class pointer.

Comment: As I suggested in a comment to your previous question, you should consider simplifying your code examples.  90% of the above code (e.g. all the template stuff) is irrelevant to your question, and it just makes it harder for people to help you ...

Comment: You are right at some point. In fact, I have trimmed most of the code from the book and only list the related one here. When present a question, I want to make sure that I present it correctly in the first place. You are right I can replace all templates with regular functions/classes. but it may also remove the some delicate points of the idea presented in the book that I don't realize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no memory-leak here (the object doesn't own any resource that needs `delete`-ing).

However, invoking `delete` on a non-base object through a pointer-to-base without a virtual destructor causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: (Though it's only by pure chance that "the object doesn't own any resource that needs `delete`-ing"; the _approach_ or _pattern_ or whatever you want to call it is susceptible to leaks in practice. Of course the UB concern trumps everything.)

Comment: nice one: typed roughly the same answer in parallel! :)

Comment: Can I put in this way, there is a bug in the code and I need to manually add a virtual destructor?

Answer (score 4):

Don't worry: there is no memory leak! What you should worry about, however, is that you invoked undefined behavior. Ah, well, this may manifest itself in a memory leak but it can also manifest itself in any other way it fancies. The rule is really simple: if you call delete on a pointer whose static type doesn't match the dynamic type, you have undefined behavior. Note that undefined behavior typically means that it work perfectly but it fails when the there are big bucks at stake, e.g. when the client is prepare to agree to the multi-million deal if this one demo works - it won't.